# Plugin for text navigation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, emacs, vi

I am using delphi 2010, and I am used to work on emacs. Really I would like to do most of my editing on a more emacs, vi way but without go out of it. Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know emacs but it's probably possible by writing a custom [keyboard binding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/Editor_KeyBinding_Sample).

Update: Delphi already includes a keyboard binding called "[New IDE Emacs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Emacs_%28System%29_Keyboard_Shortcuts)", check it out (go to Tools\Options\Editor Options\Key Mappings).

Comment: @Xichen Li: Yes, I just found it, too.

Comment: it just has a problem. Once active, I haven't found a way to select text (like shift_some-arrow, or ctrl+shift+some_arrow)